# Gremlin query on Cosmos DB: Unable to cast object of type StringField to Compose1Field

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

We have the issue with Gremlin query on Azure Cosmos DB
The query works in Gremlin Console on TinkerPop but Cosmos DB is complaining about it.

It seems to be an issue with the last `group().by(...)` step

Not sure if this is a bug or there is some workaround specific for Cosmos

The error is as follows:

Error

```
ExceptionType : InvalidCastException ExceptionMessage : Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Gremlin.Core.Runtime.StringField' to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Gremlin.Core.Runtime.Compose1Field'. Source : Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Gremlin.Core HResult : 0x80004002
```

The query is as follows:

```
g.V().hasLabel('user').as('u').
           out('userGeneratedEvent').
           outE('eventRelatedTo').as('w').inV().
           out('itemVersionOf').as('i').
           select('u','i','w').
             by('userId').
             by('itemId').
             by('weight').
           unfold().
           group().
             by(keys).
             by(select(values).fold()).
           unfold()
```

It should produce the following result:

```
==>u=[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
==>w=[5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
==>i=[1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
```

The  graph example is as follows:

```
g.addV('user').property('userId', 1)
g.addV('user').property('userId', 2)
g.addV('user').property('userId', 3)
g.addV('event').property('eventId', 1)
g.addV('event').property('eventId', 2)
g.addV('event').property('eventId', 3)
g.addV('event').property('eventId', 4)
g.addV('event').property('eventId', 5)
g.addV('itemVersion').property('itemVersionId', 1)
g.addV('itemVersion').property('itemVersionId', 2)
g.addV('itemVersion').property('itemVersionId', 3)
g.addV('itemVersion').property('itemVersionId', 4)
g.addV('itemVersion').property('itemVersionId', 5)
g.addV('itemVersion').property('itemVersionId', 6)
g.addV('itemVersion').property('itemVersionId', 7)
g.addV('item').property('itemId', 1)
g.addV('item').property('itemId', 2)
g.addV('item').property('itemId', 3)
g.addV('item').property('itemId', 4)
g.V().hasLabel('user').has('userId',1).addE('userGeneratedEvent').to(g.V().hasLabel('event').has('eventId',1))
g.V().hasLabel('user').has('userId',2).addE('userGeneratedEvent').to(g.V().hasLabel('event').has('eventId',2))
g.V().hasLabel('user').has('userId',2).addE('userGeneratedEvent').to(g.V().hasLabel('event').has('eventId',3))
g.V().hasLabel('user').has('userId',3).addE('userGeneratedEvent').to(g.V().hasLabel('event').has('eventId',4))
g.V().hasLabel('user').has('userId',3).addE('userGeneratedEvent').to(g.V().hasLabel('event').has('eventId',5))
g.V().hasLabel('event').has('eventId',1).addE('eventRelatedTo').to(g.V().hasLabel('itemVersion').has('itemVersionId',1)).property('weight', 5)
g.V().hasLabel('event').has('eventId',2).addE('eventRelatedTo').to(g.V().hasLabel('itemVersion').has('itemVersionId',1)).property('weight', 4)
g.V().hasLabel('event').has('eventId',2).addE('eventRelatedTo').to(g.V().hasLabel('itemVersion').has('itemVersionId',2)).property('weight', 1)
g.V().hasLabel('event').has('eventId',3).addE('eventRelatedTo').to(g.V().hasLabel('itemVersion').has('itemVersionId',1)).property('weight', 2)
g.V().hasLabel('event').has('eventId',3).addE('eventRelatedTo').to(g.V().hasLabel('itemVersion').has('itemVersionId',3)).property('weight', 3)
g.V().hasLabel('event').has('eventId',4).addE('eventRelatedTo').to(g.V().hasLabel('itemVersion').has('itemVersionId',4)).property('weight', 4)
g.V().hasLabel('event').has('eventId',5).addE('eventRelatedTo').to(g.V().hasLabel('itemVersion').has('itemVersionId',5)).property('weight', 1)
g.V().hasLabel('itemVersion').has('itemVersionId',1).addE('itemVersionOf').to(g.V().hasLabel('item').has('itemId',1))
g.V().hasLabel('itemVersion').has('itemVersionId',2).addE('itemVersionOf').to(g.V().hasLabel('item').has('itemId',2))
g.V().hasLabel('itemVersion').has('itemVersionId',3).addE('itemVersionOf').to(g.V().hasLabel('item').has('itemId',3))
g.V().hasLabel('itemVersion').has('itemVersionId',4).addE('itemVersionOf').to(g.V().hasLabel('item').has('itemId',1))
g.V().hasLabel('itemVersion').has('itemVersionId',5).addE('itemVersionOf').to(g.V().hasLabel('item').has('itemId',2))
g.V().hasLabel('itemVersion').has('itemVersionId',6).addE('itemVersionOf').to(g.V().hasLabel('item').has('itemId',3))
g.V().hasLabel('itemVersion').has('itemVersionId',7).addE('itemVersionOf').to(g.V().hasLabel('item').has('itemId',4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback. Currently, the Data Explorer does not support all functionality as does the Gremlin Console on Tinkerpop, which supports all Groovy language expressions.

You can refer the [MSDN Thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a286bafd-48aa-4001-927a-56963734c3c2/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-microsoftazurecosmosgremlincoreruntimestringfield-to-type?forum=azurecosmosdb) for more details.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I have submitted this to MS support, it was confirmed this is a bug and that MS has started working on it